# Salt $\rm NaCl$ at the epicenter of a nuclear explosion

Tags: nuclear-physics, isotopes

As is known, in the case of neutron irradiation, sodium is converted into the unstable isotope Na-24.
This isotope is terribly radioactive. And in the event of a nuclear strike on a salt mine or warehouse, will this salt become radioactive?
And will it be a significant additional factor of defeat?

Comment: What do you mean by a "significant factor of defeat"? That doesn't sound like a physics question.

Comment: A short lifetime means that the radiation goes away quickly.

Answer (score 4):

A nuclear explosion liberates roughly one kilogram of neutrons. (This is a nice homework problem if you've never done it. Use $\sim 200\rm\ MeV$ per fission, your favorite yield in kilotons of TNT, and concert the units.) Nearly all of these neutrons will be absorbed on environmental nuclei rather than undergoing free neutron decay. Every nucleus which absorbs a neutron is transmuted, and most of the reaction products are radioactive.

The major health risks in nuclear fallout come from biologically active radioisotopes. The two best-known are iodine-131, with a half life of about a week, and strontium-90, with a half-life of about 30 years. Iodine is concentrated by the body in the thyroid gland, so a small amount of iodine can lead to a strong localized dose. Strontium is chemically similar to calcium, and therefore accumulates in bones, where it can give a chronic exposure.

Both of these are "primary" fission products, coming directly from the uranium nucleus, rather than secondary products causes by neutron activation. When irradiating salt, neutrons would prefer to capture on the chlorine-35, making long-lived chlorine-36. Since sodium-24 has a half-life of only 14 hours, any of that which was produced would be gone in a few days.

Don't forget that the tactical purpose of nuclear weapons is to knock down buildings and destroy roads, bridges, railways, etc. Poisoning the environment is just a side effect.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossroads#Induced_radioactivity), in the Crossroads Baker underwater detonation, sodium-24 caused a lot of problems in the short term because of its high activity. OTOH, the unexploded plutonium caused far more problems because their Geiger counters and dosimeters couldn't detect it.

Comment: Oh, I hadn’t thought about seawater. In that environment sodium might be the second-biggest absorber after chlorine. A fraction of a percent of a kilomole of neutrons still makes an awful lot of activated sodium.